# How to define count without using var

Tags: scala

I have this simple function that return some `Status`:

```
def getStatus : String =
{
   //...
}
```

And i want to wait until this return specific status but still count this number of calls before exit:

```
def wait =
{
    var count = 0
    while (getStatus != "smeStatus" && count < 10) {

        // some code here
        count++
    }
}
```

How can i avoid of using `var` ?

Comment: how about a recursive implementation? If you don't plan to wait for too long it might suit your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive method that takes the count-so-far and returns it + 1:

```
def waitUntilDone(countSoFar: Int): Int = {
  if (getStatus != "smeStatus" && countSoFar < 10) {
    // some code here
    waitUntilDone(countSoFar + 1)
  } else {
    countSoFar
  }
}
// invoke it starting with 0:
val count = waitUntilDone(0)
```

Comment: Why i have this error: recursive method waitUntillDone needs result type

Comment: Recursive methods need their result type explicitly defined - notice the `: Int` at the end of the first line

Comment: If you count down and check for  `count == 0` the number of times to wait is passed on in the initial call to the recursive function. instead of being hardcoded inside

Answer (score 0):

```
  def status = ""

  def waiting: Unit = {
    def check(count: Int): Unit = {
      if(count < 10 && status != "smeStatus") {
        // do something
        check(count + 1)
      } 
    }
    check(0)
  }
```